# How to make file unreadable for certain user?

Tags: linux, encryption

For example, I have a file `/tmp/plain.txt`, and if userA do a `cat`, he will get correct content, for example, `correct content`, and if root `cat` it, he will get meaningless text, for example, `easd$qxc%sdf`. and even root copy it to HOME, he cannot get the right content.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like what NTFS encryption does.  One would hope that if Windows can do it, Linux would have a way...

Comment: You should try to find a solution based on encryption with a user specific 'key'. Unless you want to code this on your own this question is off topic for SO.

Comment: This may be possible with an encrypted FUSE file system, but I'm not sure. Another possibility is a LUKS image loop mounted by the user.

Comment: But this isn't really a programming question. You should ask on Super User or Unix & Linux sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt the file using AES symmetric encryption and keep the key safe with you. And use that key to decrypt your file and view.

You can also make it more secure by using RSA asymmetric encryption, with encrypting from a public key, and decrypting from a private key.

Answer (score 1):

If you want other users not to read your files, better make sure they do not have access to root's password. You can easily manage user permissions on files, by using [chmod](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm), or by using a file manager:

```
chmod o-rw /tmp/plain.txt
```

Where   *o* indicates all users expect you(and root), 
        *-* indicates revoking permission
        *rw* indicates reading and writing permissions

If you want a more secure method, you'll need to encrypt your home partition. Depending on which distribution you are using, you may encrypt your the partition on installation or by simply using a [partition encryption tool](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_a_non-root_file_system) in a live boot session.